# replace Location header when using .setFollowRedirect(true) with aysnchttpclient

Tags: java, asynchttpclient

I would like to replace Location header in one condition. I use the following to enable Redirect

```
client.prepareGet(request.getUrl())
             .setFollowRedirect(true)
```

What I did is to extended AsyncCompletionHandler class, and from there I @Override onHeadersReceived(),

```
@Override
public State onHeadersReceived(final HttpResponseHeaders headers) throws Exception {

String location = headers.getHeaders().get("Location").replace("itmss", "https"
);
DefaultHttpHeaders httpHeaders = new DefaultHttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.add(HEADER, location);
httpHeaders.add(headers.getHeaders());
return inner.onHeadersReceived(new HttpResponseHeaders(httpHeaders));

}
```

However, I see that the request still uses `itms` instead of `https`, which means the Location header is not replaced.

The current plan is to implement a interceptor that runs before `Redirect30xInterceptor.java`(https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/dd459294434a408cff3c65c9f5c402b82d60aaa2/client/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/netty/handler/intercept/Redirect30xInterceptor.java), and change the url.

The other plan is to do a while loop for the following code, and whenever receiving 3XX, set a new url in the next request.

```
client.prepareGet(request.getUrl())
                             .addHeader("User-Agent", request.getUserAgent())
                             .setProxyServer(proxyServer)
                             .execute(new ResponseAsyncCompletionHandler(request))
                             .toCompletableFuture();
```

The ultimate goal is to replace `itms://` to `https://`, so the next request uses `https` instead of `itms`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying more, okhttp supports interceptor easily.

If wanted to use AsyncHttp it's much more tricky. You have to implement the ResposeFilter, and from there you change the request, and setup replayRequest(true), which means a new request is made.

example code

`builder.request(new RequestBuilder(nextRequest).build()).replayRequest(true);`

https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/master/client/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/netty/handler/intercept/ResponseFiltersInterceptor.java#L62